# dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore + dojox.grid.DataGrid + 100% width and height

Tags: json, datagrid, dojo

I want a dojox.grid.DataGrid with a dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore as the data store. I want it to fill the entire screen. I don't want to specify dimensions in pixels. All the examples that I've seen specify them in pixels or use a CSV data store. I've tried using HTML elements and javascript to setup the datagrid and store.

Has anyone done this? Is there a bug? It seems like what anyone would want, but maybe it's not possible for some reason. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit to insert code:

```
<div id="gridContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

<div id="gridContainer1" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        // our test data store for this example:
        var jsonStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
            url: '/mydata.json'
        });

        var layout = [{
            field: 'id',
            name: 'id',
            width: '20px'
        },
        {
            field: 'name',
            name: 'name',
            width: '50px'
        },
        {
            field: 'owner',
            name: 'owner',
            width: '50px'
        }];

        // create a new grid:
        var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            query: {
            rowid: '*'
            },
            store: jsonStore,
            clientSort: true,
            rowSelector: '20px',
            structure: layout
        },
        document.createElement('div'));

        dojo.byId("gridContainer1").appendChild(grid.domNode);

        grid.startup();
    });
</script>
```

Depending on whether I use gridContainer or gridContainer1, it does not show or shows the grid respectively.

What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Yep - perfectly possible.
1) Page layout is the responsibility of the layout widgets (ContentPane, StackContainer, BorderContainer, TabContainer...) The grid is able to take part in a layout but you should really place it in a contianer that is designed to do layout.

2) Programatic creation can be achieved with:

```
var layout = [{
    name: "MyFirstColumnHeader",
    field: 'someColumnNameInMyData',
    width: "180px;"
  },
  {
    name: "MySecondColumnHeader",
    field: 'someOtherColumnName',
    width: "180px;"
  }
];

var emptyData = {
  identifier: 'uniqueIdOfEachItem',
  label: 'displayName',
  items: []
};
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
  data: emptyData
});
var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
  id: 'myGrid',
  query: {
    uniqueIdOfEachItem: '*'
  },
  store: store,
  structure: layout
}, gridPlaceholder);
grid.startup();
```

where

MyFirstColumnHeader is the text you would like in the first column header

someColumnInMyData is the object attribute or 'column' in the data to be displayed

gridPlaceholder is a div on the page to put the grid into (just add an empty div to ContentPane and make the style of the ContentPane to be width : 100%, height : 100%

uniqueIdOfEachItem is the property of each displayed item that marks them as unique, e.g. their primary key or ID property

This example creates a read/write store and has a simple layout, but the dojo docs should be able to help with more complex examples.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the explanation. Just to confirm:

There is no default width for columns? If I specify them via the "layout", then I can specify my container element to 100% wide and 100% high(no pun intended). Right now I do have a container element, but the odd thing is that what affects the width seems to be if I specify a width for the div that defines the dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore - not the container.

My grid's columns are dynamic. The number and their contents are determined by data from a database. So if I specify the same width for each, I guess that is fine. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I edited my question to include my code example. I've also tried it without document.createElement('div') and dojo.byId("gridContainer").appendChild(grid.domNode). Still the same problem. The container div with percentage dimensions shows nothing. While the container div pixel dimensions shows everything. Also another thing I found strange is that span elements can be used with csv data stores and but not with json. I'm specifying a 'url' for my store. I'm not keen on recreating it via javascript.

Comment: It seems the width can be 100% - not a pixel value, but height must be a pixel value.

Comment: It's really a CSS/HTML issue. The parent element of the ContentPane must have a value - even 100%. So the body element must also have a value of 100%, which messes up a lot of margins and the like. Looks like I'm going to have to rebuild the layout of my app to work with this. Thanks for your help Andy.

Comment: My single page RIA uses:

<div class="app"></div>

where the css has :

.app
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

You can add padding and margins to contained elements, but the above  is a pretty standard single page container div.
In markup you could add a ContainerPane and set its style to be width and height 100% and then when creating the grid do:

<div class="app">
    <div dojoAttachPoint="gridPlaceholder"></div>
</div>

and use the previous code I mention.